# How to add stream in coverity

Tags: analysis, coverity

I am new to Coverity Analysis. I need to add Stream in Coverity, how can I achieve this.
Below is my script

```
-solution:'nameofsolution.sln' -targets:"Rebuild" -configuration:"Release" -platform:"x64" -coverityHost:"%system.CoverityHost%" -coverityPort:%system.CoverityPort% -coverityUser:"%system.CoverityUser%" -coverityPassword:"%system.CoverityPassword%" -coverityStream:"TEST" -coverityOutputDir:"%env.CoverityWorkFolder%" -triggerType:'%teamcity.build.triggeredBy%' %ForceCoverity%.
```

Now, where and how can I add stream "TEST" in Coverity. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Are you sure that's your full script? That doesn't look like any programming language I've ever seen.  Are you trying to add a stream in your script? Or are you trying to add a stream in general, which your script will be using?

Answer (score 2):

```
cov-manage-im --host "<YOUR_HOST>" --user="<USER_NAME>" --password="<PASSWORD>" --mode streams --add --set --name:<STREAM_NAME>
```

For future reference, pass the "--help" flag to cov-manage-im to see if it has what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, could you please also tell me what if I want to add a stream to an existing project?

Comment: Linking a Stream to a Project is an additional step done in the projects mode. [Details here](https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D53400003sYSRuCAO/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-stream-under-a-project-using-command-line-optionsi-can-create-a-project-using-covmanageim-mode-projects-host-update-name-proja)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your script is right, your workflow and what kind of script it is.

To create a new stream just navigate your browser to **Coverity connect** and create one. Make sure you actually have permissions to add streams to your project.

In coverity connect you have one option like configuration in right most top corner.In that you can find Projects and stream which already created. You have to add(+stream) and name the stream name.Then It will be added.

You can use that stream in your script.

Example:

```
cov-commit-defects --dir /Users/admin/Coverity_intermediate_file_directory --host 192.178.196.125 --port 8080 --user admin --password admin123 -stream stream_name
```

Replace `stream_name` with your streams name which you have created in coverity connect.